# Operations with strings Assembly

Tags: assembly, printing, format, nasm

Let's say that I have a string with numbers `S: 1, 9, 3, 8, 5, 9`.
I have to split it in two strings `S1: 1, 3, 5` and `S2: 9, 8, 9` so that one of them contains the elements from even positions in S and the other one the elements from odd positions in S. This should be done using conditional jumps and compare instructions, but I can't solve it.

Comment: Start by writing the algorithm in a high level language, then translate the code to assembly.

Comment: Do you actually have to parse text strings with comma-separate elements, or is this really an array of integers?  And is the leading `S: ` part of the string?  Are you optimizing this for speed or code-size?  Can you use SSSE3 `pshufb` to speed up the main loop for large strings?  Or is this just a boring homework assignment?